# Required PHP version: 5.3.3 - Version found: 5.2.17... How or where do upgrade to 5.33

Tags: php, upgrade

HI I am getting this error message when trying to activate simple google cal...Required PHP version: 5.3.3 - Version found: 5.2.17...

How or where do I go in wordpress to upgrade to PHP version 5.3.3?

thanks, I am a rookie :)

Comment: WordPress does not control your PHP version, you hosting environment does.

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade php within your host (or migate to another one). The hosting server is running with very old and obsolete php version 5.2.x… The recommended version is 5.6.x (the newest one is 7.0.x, but not recommended because is still incompatible with some plugins, some themes…). If you have to use the plugin "simple google calendar" your hosting server need to run at least on php 5.3.x…

Comment: latest is 70.- not 5.7 ;)

Comment: @Mark Kaplun sorry a typing mistake